# How to calculate harmonic mean in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a data frame that looks like below. `Words`refers to the number of words per email sent.

```
sender receiver words 
a        b       10
a        c       5
a        c       15
b        a       50
b        a       30
```

I'm relatively new to Pandas. I'd like to calculate the harmonic mean of 1)the number of emails sent between each pair   2) total number of words sent between two people. How do I use `hmean()` from `scipy.stats` to obtain the desired output?

```
sender  receiver  total_emails  total_words
   a        b                   hmean([10])
   a        c                   hmean([5,15])
   b        a                   hmean([50,30])
```

For the total number of emails, I am not sure what should be the correct formula. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Teach me this basic technique” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Any PANDAS tutorial teaches you how to apply a function to the result of `groupby`.  Look for an example with `sum` or `mean`, and simply replace that function with `hmean`.

Comment: Also I would say that the question could be interpreted in different ways. i.e. you may be asking about total number of mails for the whole `df` or maybe for each pari of `sender` `receiver`, so maybe you should clarify with an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `groupby`:

```
from scipy import stats
df = df.groupby(['sender', 'receiver']).agg(stats.hmean).reset_index(name='total_words')
```

OUTPUT:

```
  sender receiver  total_words
0      a        b         10.0
1      a        c          7.5
2      b        a         37.5
```